# C# - Is there a unique "Build ID" that I can access in Asp.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compilation

I have some methods that need to run once per **build** of my web application, and not more (and not even once per application startup). The simplest way I have imagined doing this is to save a "LastBuildID" to a database, and upon each application startup, compare the "CurrentBuildID" to the last one saved in the database. If the two Build IDs are different, then it's a new build, and the methods should run.

The code would look something like this:

```
public static void RunIfNewBuild()
{
    var CurrentBuildID = ??? //what should I put here?
    var LastBuildID = DatabaseContext.GetKey("LastBuildID");
    if (CurrentBuildID != LastBuildID)
    {
        DatabaseContext.SetKey("LastBuildID", CurrentBuildID);
        Method1();
        Method2();
        Method3();
    }
}
```

So, can I access some sort of unique ID or GUID that is unique to the current build of the application? I'm using C# with Asp.NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it from assemble info like this. It will change when your code changes.

```
var CurrentBuildID = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.ModuleVersionId;
```